# Uglify.js - how to mangle just SOME global variable/function names (using Grunt)

Tags: gulp, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify, uglifyjs2

**Hi,**

I'm using Grunt and Uglify.js to mangle my code and I found out that by default the **global function/variable names are not mangled**, *which makes sense.*

I then found out, that there is a way on how to mangle them with using some settings but than **ALL the global variables get mangled.**

I need a way to mangle about **half (*some of them*)** of my variable/function names, not all of them, is there a way to achieve this?

I have no problem telling Grunt which to mangle and which not to but I cant find a solution to this...

**Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [uglify mangle options](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#mangle-options):

> `reserved` (default []) -- Pass an array of identifiers that should be
>   excluded from mangling. Example: ["foo", "bar"].

so use this option to your uglify call:

```
{ mangle: { reserved: ['dontMangleMe1', 'dontMangleMe2'] } }
```

You don't show any code and you talk about grunt but chose gulp tags for your question so I don't know how your are calling uglify.

Comment: Hi Mark, this actually led to an solution :-) , thank you